# Scala groupBy TreeMap / SortedMap?

Tags: scala

currently I have some kind of lazy groupBy stuff on scala Which should create some kind of table structure from my ordered SQL Rows,
this works great However at the end I need something like

```
Map[String, Map[String List[Object]]]
```

however the second Map should be ordered so that I could get values by the index while using zipWithIndex.
Is there way to do so?

Currently this is one of my two statements:

```
p1.toList.groupBy(_._1.layout).mapValues(_.groupBy(_._2.name).mapValues(_.map(toRow)))
```

Comment: "second Map should be ordered ". Ordered  by what?

Comment: Currently my object contains a field priority which is just a int field. Currently the SQL Query will have the p1.toList orderd after that priority however groupBy will kill the order and will be unordered